# TreeViewer expand all blocks UI

Tags: treeview, eclipse-rcp

We use RCP 3.4. With the TreeViewer there comes a handy function called "expandAll()" which expands the whole tree. But when you have many items in your tree, the UI blocks for a while. I tried to put it into a workspace job, but then I get the Error `Invalid thread access`. Then I tried to run the method with `Displac.getDefaukt().asyncExec(...)` but then the UI blocks as well.

Is there any way to put the expand-All method into a job which is possible to put in the background and to cancel, like a normal workspace Job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an ordinary tree all you can do is display a busy indicator while the tree expands, perhaps using `BusyIndicator`.

You could also look at using `DeferredTreeContentManager` which can get tree nodes in the background. This requires your tree node to implement or adapt to `IDeferredWorkbenchAdapter` which has a `fetchDeferredChildren` method which is used to do background work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i hoped there was a way, but now I have to deal with it...